# Unit Testing a Web API call - How to use Raw Request Text for Test by turning it into a HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a unit test for a Web API controller that accepts a file upload. I'd like to be able to take a Raw Request message stored as a string in a "Test Resources" file and turn it into an HttpRequestMessage. How can I do this?

For example:

```
POST http://local/api/File/26 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Authorization: f1697cb7-7dd4-49c7-87fd-3f09bc3f3d7a
ServiceId: 0
Partition: 9000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="Upload----05/06/2014 14:55:27"
Host: local
Content-Length: 179
Expect: 100-continue

--Upload----05/06/2014 14:55:27
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyTestFile.txt
Content-Type: application/x-object

Hello World!!
--Upload----05/06/2014 14:55:27--
```

This Raw request would be stored in the resource file, and I would end up with it parsed and processed into a `HttpRequestMessage` for my test.

Short of doing this manually building out the Content structure is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any easy way to parse this raw text to HttpRequestMessage...but have you considered building this multipart form data request using `MutlipartFormDataContent` instead? following is an example

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9095");

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();

MultipartFormDataContent mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
mfdc.Add(new StringContent("Hell, World!"), "greeting");
mfdc.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is from a file"))), name: "Data", fileName: "File1.txt");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/api/File", mfdc).Result;
```